# MultiDictionary implementation C#

Tags: c#

Because C# .NET does not come with a `MultiDictionary`, I implemented one based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4554628/8473031).

The `MultiDictionary` should be able to hold multiple values for one key and remove the key, if no value is assigned to the key anymore.

I wanted to implement nearly all methods, which the standard `Dictionary` provides:

```
void Add(TKey key, TValue value);
bool Remove(TKey key);
void Clear();
bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value);
```

To use the `MultiDictionary` properly some signatures needed to be changed. This is my implementation:

```
public class MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> _Data = new Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>();

    public Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>.ValueCollection Values => _Data.Values;
    public Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>.KeyCollection Keys => _Data.Keys;
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) { this[key].Add(value); }
    public bool Remove(TKey key, TValue value) { return this[key].Remove(value); }
    public void Clear() { _Data.Clear(); }
    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) { return _Data.ContainsKey(key); }
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out List<TValue> value) { return _Data.TryGetValue(key, out value); }

    private struct Entry : IEnumerable<TValue>
    {
        private readonly MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dictionary;
        private TKey Key { get; }

        internal void Add(TValue value)
        {
            if (!_Dictionary._Data.TryGetValue(Key, out var list))
                list = new List<TValue>();
            list.Add(value);
            _Dictionary._Data[Key] = list;
        }

        internal bool Remove(TValue value)
        {
            if (!_Dictionary._Data.TryGetValue(Key, out var list))
                return false;
            var result = list.Remove(value);
            if (list.Count == 0)
                _Dictionary._Data.Remove(Key);
            return result;
        }

        internal Entry(MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
        {
            _Dictionary = dictionary;
            Key        = key;
        }

        public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return !_Dictionary._Data.TryGetValue(Key, out var list) ? Enumerable.Empty<TValue>().GetEnumerator() : list.GetEnumerator();
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    }

    private Entry this[TKey key] => new Entry(this, key);
}
```

I wanted to know, if this implementation is valid (working as I expect) and if you have improvements regarding coding style, safety and so on.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> _Data` would be much more easier to handle and would have simpler implementation.

Answer (score 5):

couple of points from my side:

1. If you add same TKey instance to your List it will be added only
   once. But if you add other instance of TKey but with the same
   'content' the end result of Add method is dictionary with two keys with same content and two
   lists. Is that part of requirement?

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string X;
    public int Y;

    public Foo(string x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

var multiDict = new MultiDict<Foo, string>();

var firstFoo = new Foo("abc", 1);
multiDict.Add(firstFoo, "someValue1");
multiDict.Add(firstFoo, "someValue2");

var secondFoo = new Foo("abc", 1);
multiDict.Add(secondFoo, "someValue3");
```

2. Similar problem is for TValue, but it's related with removing elements. Solution for both cases is implementing IEqualityComparer for both TKey and TValue and force class user to inject it via constructor and use [[THIS]](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__) dictonary constructor. That will guarantee uniqueness for your key. **Please keep in mind that you should also use RemoveAll method on list to be sure that all elements that matches predicate are removed.**
3. You're incosistent with indentations of methods, curly brackets,
   whitespaces between methods. Please clean that up.
4. I don't see the point of Entry struct. You can easily get rid of it
   and put all methods in MultiDictionary class itself.
5. I would consider to change interface to more 'detailed' interface.
   What I mean by that? Let's say that Remove returns count of elements
   actually removed. Point only to consideration.
6. I will change implementation of Add method to something different,
   because you always (when key exists in dictionary or not) seeking
   through dictionary twice: first time is on TryGetValue method and
   second while attaching list to key. Attaching list to key is
   necessary only when you're creating new one.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is just a thin layer that would handle your requirements on top of the generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. You don't need any fancy or complex work to achieve that, as you're not building the collection from the scratch.

So, your implementation would use

```
Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> _Data
```

Now, you don't the struct that you have in your code, you just need to create your own interface that would have your requirements along with the minimum necessary methods or properties that needed.

Something like :

```
public interface IMultiDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{

    IEnumerable<TValue> this[TKey key] { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<TKey> Keys { get; }

    IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get; }

    int Count { get; }

    void AddOrUpdate(TKey key, TValue value);

    bool ContainsKey(TKey key);

    // remove a key along with its values
    bool RemoveKey(TKey key);

    // remove a single value from a key values.
    bool RemoveValue(TKey key, TValue value);

    //Clear All Key values, but keep the key
    void Clear(TKey key);

    bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out IEnumerable<TValue> value);
}
```

now you can do this :

```
public class MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IMultiDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> _Data = new Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>();

    public IEnumerable<TValue> Values => _Data.Values.SelectMany(x => x);

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys => _Data.Keys;

    public int Count => _Data.Count;

    public IEnumerable<TValue> this[TKey key]
    {
        get => _Data[key];
        set => AddOrUpdate(key, value);
    }

    public void AddOrUpdate(TKey key, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(key)) // if key exists
        {
            (_Data[key] as List<TValue>)?.AddRange(values);                
        }
        else
        {
            // add the new key with its value.
            _Data.Add(key, values);
        }
    }

    public void AddOrUpdate(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(key)) // if key exists
        {
            //check value and add it if not exists
            if (!_Data[key].Contains(value)) { (_Data[key] as List<TValue>)?.Add(value); }
        }
        else
        {
            // add the new key with its value.
            _Data.Add(key, new List<TValue>() { value });
        }
    }

    public void Clear(TKey key)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(key))
        {
            (_Data[key] as List<TValue>)?.Clear();
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out IEnumerable<TValue> values) => _Data.TryGetValue(key, out values);

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => _Data.ContainsKey(key);

    public bool RemoveKey(TKey key) => _Data.Remove(key);

    public bool RemoveValue(TKey key, TValue value) => ContainsKey(key) && (_Data[key] as List<TValue>)?.Remove(value) == true;

    public void Clean()
    {
        foreach (var item in _Data.Where(x => !x.Value.Any()))
        {
            _Data.Remove(item.Key);
        }
    }
    // enabling foreach loop
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => _Data.GetEnumerator();

}
```

*(NOTE : I skipped validations just to minimize the code for demonstration purpose).*

If you see the `AddOrUpdate` there is two overloads (one accepts single value, and the other accepts a collection). This would give more flexibility when you adding or updating a key. And since each key has a collection of values, we needed something like `RemoveKey` and `RemoveValue` you can rename them to `Remove` but I found it would be more readable this way. Both will come in handy. The `Clean()` method can be called whenever you need to delete empty keys.

The use of `IEnumerable` is to have the minimum collection requirement, meaning, it'll be flexible with other collection types, since most generic collections (including Array) implements it.

Answer (score 1):

Both Karol and iSR5 have some good points, and I can't add something new.

One thing you should be aware of, if you consider to use iSR5's `IEnumerable<TValue>`-approach, is as follows:

```
  MultiDictionary<int, int> dict = new MultiDictionary<int, int>();

  List<int> data = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).ToList();
  IEnumerable<int> query = data.Where(i => i % 3 == 0);

  dict.AddOrUpdate(0, query);
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dict[0]));
  data.Remove(15);
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dict[0]));
```

which outputs:

```
3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30
3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30
```

As you can see, the content of an entry in `dict` is changed outside `dict` itself. IMO this can lead to undesired and unexpected behavior, that can be difficult to debug and find, for instance if the original data is maintained "far away" from `dict`. I can only recommend that you have a concrete container type as value of the inner dictionary `_Data` - and it should only be maintained/accessible by the dictionary itself.

Else I see no reason for `MultiDictionary<K, V>` class at all, as you could just have a normal `Dictionary<K, IEnumerable<T>>` that is transparent in respect to the value container.